# Is my 10 year multi-entry visit visa (to the UK) ending 2026 still valid if my Tier 4 visa expired in 2021?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I applied for a long-term visit visa to UK in 2016. I got the visa for 10 years, ending 2026. Subsequently, I got admitted to the University of Manchester for Master's in 2019. My Tier 4 student visa expired in 2021.

Now, can I still travel on my original visitor visa till 2026? My original visa was never cancelled i.e., there is no "recommend cancel without prejudice" on my original visit visa. Does that mean it is still valid?

Please let me know if anyone knows anything, or has been in a similar situation. Thank you.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship? What was the reason you qualified for a long-term SVV  in 2016? Does that reason(s) still apply and/or are your current personal circumstances significantly different?

Comment: I am Pakistani. I believe I qualified because of very strong ties to my home country and very strong financial backing. Basically, there's a lot that ties me back to my home country. Yes, those reasons still apply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
You have been granted a SVV before getting your tier 4, if you didn't overstay, it is still valid as expected as Tier 4 and SVV are two different visas with two different applications and stickers, one doesn't erase the other

Comment: Thank you. This "Extant Leave" policy is worrying me because it seems like you can't hold two leaves at one time: 

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/extant-leave-ecb22/extant-leave-ecb22#:~:text=Applicants%20who%20already%20have%20entry,an%20application%20for%20further%20leave.

However, they did not cancel my SVV. Do you think they might see this as an issue at border control?

Comment: I don't know about that, normally you're all good (though the IO might have a weird look on that as they may think that you'll want to work there now that your studies are over, so be prepared to produce documentation) I'd contact UKVI to be certain before traveling @Mary_1D96

Comment: @Mary_1D96 Do you still meet the eligibility requirements to enter the UK as a visitor? Eg ties to home country, sufficient funds etc?

Comment: Hey yes, I do! I have a job here. My entire family is here. My fiance is here. I am just going to attend my convocation which was delayed because of COVID and see my friends who still reside there. I even have my return tickets booked.

Comment: @Nicholas Formichella The official source quoted by the OP doesn’t support your answer IMHO

Comment: @Traveller there's also this (please take a look at Annex B) which means I'm good to go: https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/170583/response/422329/attach/4/Annex%20A%2028317.pdf?cookie_passthrough=1

Too confusing.

Comment: @Mary_1D96 Is Annex B published on the official UK gov site? The content on WhatDoTheyKnow may not be current. Personally, I would check the validity of your visit visa with UKVI before travelling.

Comment: @Mary_1D96 Both Annex A and Annex B mention "short term" and Annex A defines that as "6 months or less". Your Tier 4 student visa appears to have had a longer duration. If it did, then it appears that your earlier visa should have been cancelled. I strongly recommend adding to your question both of the links and all the additional information you have in comments here, and then awaiting a different answer. If an ECO thinks your visa should have been cancelled when you present it at the border, it could be cancelled there and then.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I should do that. However, I must add that short term work visas (mentioned in Annex B) can last up to 2 years. So I don't think 6 months is the limit. It's all a bit vague.